# Write code to iterate all files in a directory and append each file's path to a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, oop, data-science, argparse

I need to achieve the following in my python module.

1. Get a directory as an argument through the argparse module
2. Use that directory to iterate through all the files present in that directory.
3. Later, append only the CSV files to a dictionary and store them there.

I have tried os.walk, but it does not return anything.

I have written code to get a directory as input and then iterate through it for files. But it throws errors.

Below is the code

```py
 import argparse
 import os
 import re
    
 # Accepting arguments for source_directory, my_sql connection details and table name to 
   update the MySQL entries to
    
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Utility to update MySQL tables on remote host')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--source_dir', help='Enter Path For CSV File')
    
args = parser.parse_args()
    
# Empty dictionary to store list CSV files in directory
files_in_dir = {}
    
# Function to iterate through the source_directory and read-only CSV files and append them 
   to files_in_dir dictionary
    
if args.source_dir:
    for file in args.source_dir:
    
        if os.path.abspath(file.name).endswith('.csv'):
            files_in_dir[(os.path.abspath(file.name))] = 0
    
        else:
            print("The file %s is not a .csv file and it will be ignored" % (file.name))
    
print(files_in_dir)
```

And this is the error when executed through the terminal.

```sh
 python3 sourcecheck.py -s /home/thepredator/Desktop/VOIS/csv_files/*
usage: sourcecheck.py [-h] [-s SOURCE_DIR]
sourcecheck.py: error: unrecognized arguments: /home/thepredator/Desktop/VOIS/csv_files/Book1.csv /home/thepredator/Desktop/VOIS/csv_files/Build.py /home/thepredator/Desktop/VOIS/csv_files/car_data.csv /home/thepredator/Desktop/VOIS/csv_files/db.py /home/thepredator/Desktop/VOIS/csv_files/Edited.csv /home/thepredator/Desktop/VOIS/csv_files/Iris.csv /home/thepredator/Desktop/VOIS/csv_files/Lab_Python_for_Data_Analytics.ipynb /home/thepredator/Desktop/VOIS/csv_files/startupNaN.csv /home/thepredator/Desktop/VOIS/csv_files/startupog.csv /home/thepredator/Desktop/VOIS/csv_files/text.csv
```

I have written the above code by watching different videos. Please help me fix the errors. Also, I'm not a python expert.

Comment: You're argument parser only expects a single positional argument (the "source directory"), but you're passing many positional arguments from the command line (the paths to every file in the source directory). Take a look at the output of `echo /home/thepredator/Desktop/VOIS/csv_files/*` to see why. Remember that `*` is expanded by shell before your script sees the command line arguments. Presumably you want just pass the directory name to your script, `/home/thepredator/Desktop/VOIS/csv_files`.

Comment: @Brian  Your suggestion woked fine I guess but it now shows a different error.```python3 sourcecheck.py -s/home/thepredator/Desktop/VOIS/csv_files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thepredator/Desktop/VOIS/sourcecheck.py", line 26, in <module>
    if os.path.abspath(file.name).endswith('.csv'):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'```             I think there is a problem with the file.name thing.  Can you please help me out with it??

Comment: `args.source_dir` is just the **dir name** that you provided in the input.  It is not the directory itself.  It is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `files_dir = {}` line to

`files_in_dir = { key:0 for key in os.listdir(args.source_dir) if os.path.abspath(key).endswith(".csv") }`

and it seems work.

if-else in for statement version following requests:

```py
for key in os.listdir(args.source_dir):
    if os.path.abspath(key).endswith(".csv"):
        files_in_dir[key] = 0
    else:
        print(f"The file {key} is not a .csv file and it will be ignored")
```

Comment: This works fine. Can you please explain me key:0 thing in the code?

Comment: `key:0` means `files_in_dir[(os.path.abspath(file.name))] = 0`

listdir() gets all files and key have a file name.

0 is from your code

Comment: can you please show me how to put this code in an if...else.. I need to print the non-csv files which are skipped.  It should have this functionality ```else: print("The file %s is not a .csv file and it will be ignored" % (file.name))```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code`

```
import os

files = os.listdir("/path_to_directory")    

csv = list(filter(lambda f: f.endswith('.csv'), files))
```

csv has all the files with .csv extension

Comment: How can I pass the argument from the command line to the directory variable?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-python/                                                Here you can see dummy code for a command line program, you can use the same concepts.